# Storing complex object in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

As per Java Concurrency in Practice below code can throw assertion Error:

If a thread other than the publishing thread were to call
assertSanity, it could throw AssertionError

```
  public class Holder {
private int n;
public Holder(int n) { this.n = n; }
public void assertSanity() {
if (n != n)
throw new AssertionError("This statement is false.");
}
}

// Unsafe publication
public Holder holder;
public void initialize() {
holder = new Holder(42);
}
```

Question is: If I save, an object which refers to other objects in a ConcurrentHashMap, is there a possibility that certain updates on this object graph will not be in sync, in a multi-threaded environment due to same reasons as mentioned for above example?

Though root node in object graph will always be updated in map for all threads, but what about other objects which are referred as fields in root node, if these are not final or volatile ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, I should have read complete chapter before asking question. This is what later part of chapter says:

> Mutable objects: If an object may be modified after construction, safe
>   publication ensures only the visibility of the as-published state.
>   Synchronization must be used not only to publish a mutable object, but
>   also every time the object is accessed to ensure visibility of
>   subsequent modifications. To share mutable objects safely, they must
>   be safely published and be either thread-safe or guarded by a lock.

So using CHM or any thread safe collection is unsafe in a multithreaded environment, unless you synchronize changes to your mutable objects in CHM or these objects are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

A ConcurrentHashMap guarantee that all operation with reference (link to object), that be saved in a ConcurrentHashMap, are thread-safe, however, of course, a ConcurrentHashMap can not guarantee a thread-safe every objects, with reference(link) be stored in a ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: So you mean, changes in object graph will be out of sync, if same CHM is accessed in different threads ?

Comment: If we speak about object graph that all node's links save only in CHM, yes, it be sync.

Comment: Am still not getting straight answer, may be my question is not clear. In CHM you just put individual nodes(Objects), which I know is guaranteed to be in sync, but what about several objects(fields in these nodes) to which these nodes refer to ?